# How to synchronize time in Ticker?

Tags: java-me, ticker

```
Date d = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
String datum = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+"h "+
c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"."+c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
//String Dateinstring = new String(datum.toString());
Ticker t = new Ticker (datum.toString());
joro.removeCommand(show);
joro.addCommand(back);
joro.setTicker(t);
String label = command.getLabel();
```

Code above got still value and repeating it trough scroll. How can it be synchronized with real-time? (Time may jitter to 1 minute).